# Convert Windows 10 digital license to real license key?

Tags: windows, license

I *HATE* these license of Windows 10 Pro that I bought on the machine, from the Microsoft Store, while I was logged into my Microsoft account.

Is there a any way to can convert or exchange those digital licenses to the old-school fixed xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx type of licenses?

I'm having major headaches re-activating a license on machines where I am going P2V and it was a Store-bought digital license, and I just want plain old style licenses for any remaining machines before I convert them to VMs.

Comment: You were sent the license key when you made your purchase. If you lost the email.  You can use [ShowKeyPlus](https://github.com/Superfly-Inc/ShowKeyPlus/releases/tag/ShowkeyPlus).  You only have a digital entitlement in order to make it easier to install on the same machine.  Be sure to remove your current machine from your MS account otherwise activatation will likely fail. If you upgraded from Windows 10 Home to Windows 10 Professional then your upgrade license doesn’t have transfer rights

Answer (score 1):

If you bought a retail version of Windows 10, you should
have gotten a product key. If you have mislaid it, you need to
contact Microsoft with a proof of purchase.

If you instead upgraded to Windows 10 from an activated Windows 7/8/8.1, you will not have a product key. Instead, the PC gets registered on Microsoft activation servers with a digital license (formerly called digital entitlement) that will always be used to activate Windows 10 on that PC.

However, you may link your Microsoft account to that license on your device. This way you may reactivate Windows by using the Activation troubleshooter if you make a hardware change later, such as replacing the motherboard, just by logging into your Microsoft account.

Using a recent Windows 10 release,
you can now use the product key from Windows 7/8/8.1 that was previously used to activate Windows on this same device,
by going to `Settings > Update & security > Activation` and selecting `Change Product Key`, and you can do this even for a clean install of Windows 10.

See the article
[How to link your Windows 10 product key to a Microsoft account](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-link-your-windows-10-product-key-microsoft-account).

Answer (score 0):

This article will provide you with lots of information: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/windows-10-how-to-tell-what-type-of-activation-i/ea12f936-cecb-493c-81f5-ba89bcda3b6d?auth=1

Basically, you can't convert your digital license to a product key.

EDIT (Quoting source article):
There are four ways to obtain an actual product key, on of them is when you purchase a copy of Windows 10 from an authorized retailer.
The article states, "Buy it from the Microsoft Store and you are digitally entitled, buy it from a Retailer and you need a key to re-install and activate Windows 10."
The article also states, "Should your computer become unusable you need to call the store before re-installing your store purchased “Retail” version on another computer."
So that means that if you want to use your digital license on a different computer you have to call the Microsoft store first.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Even though the author has a digital license, he still has a license key, so this answer is actually incorrect.  While the quoted information is valid, the answer more incomplete, because it does not provide a solution to the author's problem (there is indeed solution).  Perhaps you should do more research and provide that solution?

Comment: So I guess the user @Ramhound is correct when you should use the app ShowKeyPlus to reveal what your license key is.

Answer (score 0):

I too just found this pain. I have a second hard drive on my System76 Linux machine, dedicated to dual-booting Windows (to access the GPU directly for CAD). When booted physically, the digital license (bought from the Microsoft store) auths with Microsoft and my version of Windows is active.

When I am under Linux and use VMware Workstation to boot that hard drive inside a VM Windows reports it's not activated and then begins the lovely ritual of going to sleep every hour along with watermarks and push notifications. There are various troubleshooting steps that both the automated helper and Microsoft support will walk you through, but all will result in an array of different error codes which essentially distill down to "too much hardware had changed for Microsoft to believe you're using only one instance of Windows".

I also tried the other suggestions on this page to use "ShowKeyPlus" to get the digital license key (which I did get) but then when booted under the VM I used the "change license key" and it reported an error that particular key was invalid or could not be used in this way.

I had called Microsoft support on 3 separate occasions which, their solution was to reinstall Windows and then login with my Microsoft account and everything would be fixed.... I did reinstall Windows, and had the exact same issue... to which the next support person suggested reinstalling Windows.

In the end I contacted Microsoft Store Support and requested a refund for the digital license. I then purchased a "physical" copy, i.e. the USB version. They told me that a license key is included with that, so I'll update if that fixes it when I receive it in the mail.

## Update:

That seemed to do the trick. I got my physical USB Windows install box today, inside is a little pull-out card with the license key on a sticker as per what you've seen before stuck to the back of a case. After entering this key in on the "Change Product Key" screen while booted in VM mode the key was accepted and Windows was activated. I then rebooted to the physical side and the activation screen showed an error for a split second (couldn't even read it) but then flashed to "Activated".

One thing to note, it still says "Activated by a digital license that's tied to your account"... even though it's very much so the physical key version. I do have my account logged in with my Microsoft account, so perhaps it auto-linked the two. But in any case, it all seems to be working as intended.